# Question about Automate the Boring Stuff: Chapter 4

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a beginner to programming, and I just have a question about Automate the Boring Stuff: Chapter 4. There is a practice project where you have to reformat a grid in a certain way. The following is my code:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(0, len(grid[0])):
    for j in range(0, len(grid)):
        print(grid[j][i], end = "")
    print("")
```

Output:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

I understand how to arrange this code using the "for" loops. However, I am confused as to why you must include the 'end = "" ' in order to achieve this. I am also wondering why you must include the last 'print(" ")' statement in order to do this as well.

Comment: Try leaving those elements out and you'll see what they do. If you don't like loops, but reading up in the docs, try: `print('\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*grid))))`

Answer (score 1):

In the for loops, you are printing not each row, but each character. A normal print statement defaults to end='\n', or a new line. For example, if I run:

```
mylist = ['this', 'list', 'right', 'here']
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

The output will be:

```
this
list
right
here
```

What the end keyword does is change how the print statement ends each print. in my same example, if I instead added end = '-', it would add a hyphen between each item in the list.

```
this-list-right-here-
```

Note that it adds the hyphen to the last word as well. each time the print statement is called, it prints what you ask, followed by what you put as "end".

Because you're adding an empty string as end, each character is printed right after the previous one, but then it does move on to a new line. Why? When your code finishes a row of 'j's, it moves on to the next index of rows - or i. When it does this, you're printing a blank string, but you're doing that with the default end value, which is end='\n'. It would be more clear if the example made you explicitly write that part out. Here, it's not what you print that matters, but what is added to that by the default end - a new line. So you're going through each character, printing it out and then continuing without a new line until you reach the end of the row, at which point you print a new line and continue on.

You could also replace that final print("") with print("\n", end="") and get the same result.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps. However, for that last print(" ") statement, does printing it in that specific spot make it connect to the 'for loops'? i.e., it will print out exactly 9 characters before moving onto a new line, because it is connected to the loops?

Comment: Yeah, so it's actually "in-between" the for-loops. You have two loops, so you do one loop on each loop of the other one. Big loop and little loop. After each little loop, you print("") before going to the next big loop. Your big loops are on the list of lists, and your little loops are on each list within that list of lists.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Is there a name for this sort of thing? Just wondering because I did not know that this sort of idea existed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `print()` function appends a newline to whatever it prints.

You can disable this behavior by passing it the keyword `end`, which lets you set what it prints instead of a newline. This could be a comma, a space, *multiple* newlines, whatever - or, it could be the empty string, meaning it prints nothing.

This is the only way to print multiple things on the same line, as (obviously) if you don't get rid of the 'automatic newline' somehow, everything appears on its own line, which isn't what you want.

Then you call `print()` again, either with no argument or with an empty string, and let it append a newline as its default behavior.

---

In case it helps to illustrate, the following are functionally equivalent:

```
print()
print('')
print('', end='\n')
print('\n', end='')
```

In each case, they print one newline and nothing else.